# How i can access gtm shell with ansible playbook command

Tags: ansible

I am stuck at this,I could easily set source for [GT.M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GT.M) but after this, when I fire gtm command it get stuck,don't get out of it also,somebody please help me out.

my code is as follow:

```
---
- name: Copying files on local machine and printing Hello msg.
  hosts: webservers
  user: onkar
  remote_user: vistaehr
  gather_facts: False  
  #sudo: False
  tasks:  
    - name: copying local file
      copy: src=/home/onkar/onkar/Ansible/HELLO.m dest=/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr
      #shell: rm pwd.txt

    - name: Print Success
      debug: msg="success"

    - name: changing ownership of file
      #copy: src=/home/onkar/onkar/Ansible/HELLO.m dest=/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr
      shell: chown vistaehr:vistaehr /home/vistaehr/VistA/testr/HELLO.m

    - name: Setting Source        
      shell: . /home/vistaehr/VistA/env && gtm    

    - name: Print Success
      debug: msg="success"

    - name: zlinking given file      
      shell: zlink "/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr/HELLO.m"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtm` starts a console, it is an interactive process. Ansible is waiting until the called command is exiting. Since the program never exits, your ansible task will never complete.

What are you trying to archive with calling `gtm` from Ansible? If you want to start a service you should look into the [`service`](http://docs.ansible.com/service_module.html) module or check out `systemd` or `init.d` depending on your system.

Running a command **in** `gtm` you can do with piping:

```
echo 'zlink "/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr/HELLO.m"' | gtm
```

Or as an ansible task:

```
- name: Setting Source and zlinking given file
  shell: . /home/vistaehr/VistA/env && echo 'zlink "/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr/HELLO.m"' | gtm
```

Comment: plz see the code daniel after entering in gtm console i want to execute that zlink command so

Comment: You have to find a way how that works with `gtm`, that's not an ansible issue. `gtm` has to exit before the playbook continues. Even if it would continue, you can not run a command inside `gtm` by calling the shell module again. It might be as simple as `echo 'zlink "/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr/HELLO.m"' | gtm` if it support piping.

Comment: thanks daniel this echo 'zlink "/home/vistaehr/VistA/testr/HELLO.m"' | gtm piping works :)